# Выбрать строки из таблицы, по условию из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, select

Есть две таблицы: history_oper

```
date_oper | user_phone |      sms
 01.06.20 | 7999999999 | txtxtx 1234 txtxt
```

и err_opers

```
  dat    |     tel    |  sum
01.06.20 | 7999999999 | 1234
```

Нужно из history_oper выбрать строки ошибочных опереаций, таблица err_opers. Сложность в том, что в первой таблице в поле sms содержится текст, в котором есть сумма (1234) а во второй таблице указана только эта сумма без текста. Сделал так

```
SELECT * FROM `history_oper` WHERE 
`date_oper` IN (SELECT dat FROM err_opers)
AND `user_phone` IN (SELECT tel FROM err_opers)    
AND `sms` LIKE IN(SELECT sum FROM err_opers)
```

Как правильно записать третье условие?

Comment: `sms like concat('%', ..., '%')`. Но меня в отдельных select смущает то, а действительно ли вы хотите что бы были выбраны записи history у которых каждое из условий сработало с _РАЗНЫМИ_ строками err_opers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос ваш неверен, он выдаст лишние записи. Пробуйте, так

```
SELECT `history_oper`.* FROM `history_oper` 
INNER JOIN err_opers
  ON `history_oper`.`date_oper` = err_opers.dat
  AND `user_phone` = err_opers.tel
WHERE
   `sms` LIKE CONCAT('%',err_opers.sum,'%')
```

Comment: спасибо исправил